# Grails test integration service injection

Tags: grails, testing, groovy, integration-testing

I want to do a full integration test which uses Services that will call other services (I'm using grails 2.4.3). 
It all works good but when there is an Services within a Service it goes only *2 levels deep* and *it doesn't go any deeper*.
**The question is: How can I make the test use all sub-services necessary**

```
class ImportServiceTests extends GroovyTestCase {  

    def grailsApplication
    def fatherService

    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void 'test1'() {
        String a= fatherService.function() // ->subService -> null
    }
}
```

Comment: With grails 2.4.x spock is the default testing framework and your integration spec should extends grails.test.spock.IntegrationSpec. Do you have the same issue with this base class?

Comment: Yes the same happens with extending grails.test.spock.IntegrationSpec

Comment: We don't have such issues. Are you able to attach your project? At least give code of the services and method which is tested.

Answer (score 1):

my error was in the test call in the grails parameters

corrected from

```
test-app -unit: ...package.class.method -Dgrails.env=integration
```

to

```
test-app integration: ...package.class.method
```

Comment: This was helpful for me. We couldn't get integration tests to inject the collaborating services without the "integration:" flag.